# What is the most optimal way to compare items in a list of structs and update accordingly?

Tags: elixir

I'm doing a multiplayer rock paper scissors game to learn Elixir. My game structure holds a list of players and a winner. I want to recursively iterate through each player after they have selected their choice which updates the score (player1 is compared against others players, then the next, etc. until all have been scored). I'm trying to figure out the optimal way to update the game, but everything I have tried seems mediocre when it comes to performance.  What would be the best approach?

Link to specific game logic:
https://github.com/onesneakymofo/rock_paper_scissors/blob/master/lib/rock_paper_scissors/judge.ex

Structure:

```
%RockPaperScissors.Game{
  players: [
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "rock", name: "Mandude", score: 0},
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "paper", name: "Tophlove", score: 0},
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "scissors", name: "T. Milla", score: 0},
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "scissors, name: "K-pop", score: 0}
  ],
  winner: nil
}
```

Expected input:

```
players: [
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "rock", name: "Mandude", score: 0},
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "paper", name: "Tophlove", score: 0},
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "scissors", name: "T. Milla", score: 0},
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "scissors, name: "K-pop", score: 0}
  ]
```

Expected output:

```
players: [
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "rock", name: "Mandude", score: 2},
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "paper", name: "Tophlove", score: 1},
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "scissors", name: "T. Milla", score: 1},
    %RockPaperScissors.Player{choice: "scissors, name: "K-pop", score: 1}
  ]
```

Comment: Can you post the exact input / expected output?

Comment: @Dogbert I have added the expected output / input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First prepare the data and then map the whole:

```rb
players = [
  %{choice: "rock", name: "Mandude", score: 0},
  %{choice: "paper", name: "Tophlove", score: 0},
  %{choice: "scissors", name: "T. Milla", score: 0},
  %{choice: "scissors", name: "K-pop", score: 0}
]

winners =
  %{"paper" => "rock",
    "rock" => "scissors",
    "scissors" => "paper"}

counts =
  players
  |> Enum.group_by(& &1.choice)
  |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, Enum.count(v)} end)
  |> Enum.into(%{})

players =
  Enum.map(players, fn %{choice: choice, score: score} = p ->
    %{p | score: score + counts[winners[choice]]}
  end) 
#⇒ [
#    %{choice: "rock", name: "Mandude", score: 2},
#    %{choice: "paper", name: "Tophlove", score: 1},
#    %{choice: "scissors", name: "T. Milla", score: 1},
#    %{choice: "scissors", name: "K-pop", score: 1}
#  ]
```

Comment: Aleksei,

this is super slick, but I would prefer to do it recursively for learning purposes.  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Well, you should not be a slave of the approach. Recursion is great when you need to reduce a list. Here the collecting of the accumulated data upfront is unavoidable (or the complexity will increase from `O(N)` to `O(N²)`.) This is basically not a task you want to solve with recursion. OTOH, you might collect sums recursively, but this is not any harder than calculating fibonacci, so I’d left it to you. Sooner or later you’ll meet the task that requires recursion, and trust me, it’ll literally yell at you “recurse me!” :)